# How do I loop over only certain elements of a dictionary in a variable with multiple indices/arrays?

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I have a binary decision variable that takes one element from 5 dictionaries (day, time, team, month, stadium) to create an optimal schedule for a sports team. How do I specify certain values from each dictionary to always equal 1 in constraints?

Essentially I'm trying to create constraints for a sports schedule, which is optimized using a goal program. I want to write a constraint so that there is only 1 game at 8:00 in Jan, for all teams in city x and day y.

```
day = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed"]
time = ["7:00", "8:00", "9:00"]
team = ["Lakers", "Warriors", "Kings"]
month = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"]
city = ["LA", "SF", "Sac"]

for i in day:
  for j in time:
    for k in team:
      for l in month:
        for m in city:
          model += z[i,1,k,0,m] <= 1
```

I hope to constrain certain elements from each dictionary in my final result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would use itertools to avoid too nesting of my loops.
Then, I replace original arrays that I am iterating over with smaller subsets where required. Here is example:

```
import itertools

day = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed"]
time = ["7:00", "8:00", "9:00"]
team = ["Lakers", "Warriors", "Kings"]
month = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"]
city = ["LA", "SF", "Sac"]

time_filtered = ["8:00", ]
month_filtered = ["Jan", ]

for i, j, k, l, m in itertools.product(
                        day, time_filtered, team, month_filtered, city):
    model += z[i,j,k,l,m] <= 0
```

There is a problem with your code. when you use "for x in iterable", you get elements of that iterable in x. For example, "for i in day" would return "Mon" on first iteration, not 0.
So, I would say z[i,1,k,0,m] is actually z[i,"8:00", k, "Jan", m].

If you do want to have indexes instead of values, you could use range(len(iterable)).
and [1,], [0,] for filtered values.

what is model and what is z is not clear from your code. None of them look like dictionaries (you reference dictionary in the header). Do you mean lists in the header? or there is some hidden dict?

Comment: Thank you for answering! Model is the name I assigned to my linear programming problem using pulp library on python. z here is a binary decision variable with 5 indices (day, time, team, month, city), all of which are lists.